# Slicing JavaScript TypedArray multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, typed-arrays

I was trying to split a typedArray into smaller chunks, with this simple code snippet:

```
const buf = new Uint8Array([0x02, 0x00, 0x07, 0x63, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x6e, 0x65, 0x63, 0x74, 0x00, 0x3f, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x03, 0x61, 0x70, 0x70, 0x02])
const len = 5

for (let i=0; i<buf.length;){
  const chunk = buf.slice(i, len)
  console.log("Chunk", chunk, "from", i, "to", i + chunk.length)
  if (chunk.length) {
    i += chunk.length
  } else {
    console.log("Chunk is empty")
    break
  }
}
```

But what I found is that `slice` only works the first iteration, returning empty chunks the next ones.

I noticed that it also happens in Node.js, if I replace the first line with:

```
const buf = Buffer.from([0x02, 0x00, 0x07, 0x63, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x6e, 0x65, 0x63, 0x74, 0x00, 0x3f, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x03, 0x61, 0x70, 0x70, 0x02])
```

Why this behaviour?

Comment: because `slice(from, to)` takes two indices with `from <= index && index < to`, not an index + length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument to the typed array `slice` method is the end point, not the length of the slice (the regular non-typed array slice works the same).

[From MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/slice)

> ```
> typedarray.slice([begin[, end]])
> ```

This means on the second call, it slices from 5 to 5, or an empty slice.

Instead, do `buf.slice(i, i + len)`.

```js
const buf = new Uint8Array([0x02, 0x00, 0x07, 0x63, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x6e, 0x65, 0x63, 0x74, 0x00, 0x3f, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x03, 0x61, 0x70, 0x70, 0x02])
const len = 5

for (let i=0; i<buf.length;){
  const chunk = buf.slice(i, i + len)
  console.log("Chunk", chunk, "from", i, "to", i + chunk.length)
  if (chunk.length) {
    i += chunk.length
  } else {
    console.log("Chunk is empty")
    break
  }
}
```